# auto-open a question if it has a very high amount of upvotes

Tags: feature-request, voting, closed-questions, up-votes, reopen-closed

EDIT: i have accepted (by upvoting) the accepted answer in [Question is very popular but closed (not constructive) - Shouldn't it be reopened for users' benefit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155531/question-is-very-popular-but-closed-not-constructive-shouldnt-it-be-reopened). That stackoverflow does not want everything is a good argument, even if it just could be hidden and even if very popular subjects do not develop further that way.
END EDIT

Example:

[Getting started with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell)

Numbers: Friday, 2013.11.1

Question:

- 621 upvotes
- 812 times favourite question
- 184 upvotes for comment: 'Why is it that the most helpful questions I find on SO are always "NOT CONSTRUCTIVE"?'
- 64 upvotes for comment 'Amen, @kaustubh. It is a disease Stack Overflow has contracted, and it is running out of control. Sad, but I don't think it can be reversed at this point'
  (well i think it can)

Accepted Answer:

- 1073 upvotes
- 160 upvotes for comment 'This is a really remarkable answer. +1 seems almost mean. Thank you'

4 more answers with >= 30 upvotes

On the other Hand, the [admin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) who closed the question has Questions/Answers related to 1,057 tags, but:

- 0 Questions/Answers tagged 'Haskell'
- 7 Questions/Answers tagged 'functional programming' (2 accepted answers)

I think, this is quite a disbalance, if one guy without much experience in a subject can stop the subject, even if it interests a tousand guys (maybe more).

I suggest therefore to **Auto-open a question if it has a very high amount of upvotes**.

Advantage:

- Admins can say: "Ok, everybody upvote this and it will reopen."
- it gives users another reason to be proactive and upvote stuff they like.

Disadvantage:

- Admins *may* say: "I am not sure/I dont care, lets just close it for now, as everybody can upvote this anyway and it will reopen."

Maybe there are better solutions.

Whatever you think/decide, i think that this specific question deserves clearly to be reopened as the problem of using it in Practice is a concrete one. If you do not believe me, try to write an increment function in that language.

Comment: Popularity does not have a direct correlation with quality. See [Justin Bieber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_bieber)

Comment: @JonW Popularity in Haskell maybe does

Comment: The one moderator who closed it might not have much subject knowledge (that we know of), but will have an excellent grasp on which kind of questions the site has determined are not appropriate. That doesn't mean the content has no value, but those questions (in general) are not good for the site.

Comment: Questions like that are considered way to broad for Stack Overflow.  There was one time that they were permitted and accepted (hence the huge # of upvotes) but the **community** (not a moderator) decided that they don't think those questions are nearly as valuable as they appear to be and now they are no longer welcome.

Comment: But why does it need to be reopened?  It is in no danger of getting deleted. All closing does is prevent more answers.  Are the existing answers not sufficient?

Comment: Popularity is not correlated with either quality nor suitability to the site.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "but the community (not a moderator) decided that they don't think those questions are nearly as valuable as they appear to be and now they are no longer welcome." References?

Comment: @Nils personal experience.  Everything on this site is community moderated.

Comment: @Nils Just research a bit. There are tons of past meta discussions on such subjects.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "Are the existing answers not sufficient?" There may be new ones. And it in general depresses users if something is closed. See the upvoted negative comment on the page i refer to in my question.

Comment: @psubsee2003, Bart "personal experience" and "Just research a bit" is not a reference.

Comment: @Nils Such statements as in the upvoted comment are usually pretty self-centred. (Though most likely meant well). They are based on a "this is useful to me" sentiment. But they don't take into account whether or not such questions are ultimately useful for the site as a whole. They might be popular, and you might find something of use there, but they ultimately have several problems that made the community decide we should no longer support them.

Comment: @Nils Refusing to "research a bit" and demanding the evidence of a general shift in community attitude to be handing to you on a plate, via a few meta links, might be construed as a little lazy on your part.

Comment: @Bart "But they don't take into account whether or not such questions are ultimately useful for the site as a whole" - "invite sharing experiences over opinions" in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask can mark a useful question. And if an answer to such a question gets one thousand+ upvotes and that question is closed - that is a bad decision.

Comment: It isn't so much if you read up a bit on what the goals of the site are, and what has been discussed in the past, particularly on the problems associated to such questions.

Comment: @Duncan Jones Closing constructive questions might be construed as a little suspect on your part.

Comment: @Nils Please don't get into all that nonsense. This is not a duel. I'll happily supply you with some links at some point, if I have the time. But we simply expect users to do some of their own research. That's all.

Comment: @Bart I have read not too few questions before and as a result (i found no feature request that fitted) i have decided to ask that question. It took me one hour. It took you 5 mins do give me 10+ downvotes. Truth is YOU did not do enough research (I am referring to Duncan Jones here).

Comment: @Nils In case you are not familiar, down-votes on meta signify disagreement with an idea. They do not have the same negative connotations as on the main site. So people are merely disagreeing that this would be a good feature.

Comment: Especially so for feature requests. See the part on voting here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: In my time at wikipedia i have experienced the same suspect absence of common sense. It is a LIE that keeping a question open hurts most guys. TRUTH is: not closing it hurts a few guys.

Comment: @Nils But that is why we distinguish between closed questions and *deleted* questions. The one you linked to is known to be of value to people, so it hasn't been deleted. But allowing more answers to a question that is no longer consider on-topic for this site is not helpful. And it is important that future users can't use such questions as justification to write their own similar off-topic questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question is very popular but closed (not constructive) - Shouldn't it be reopened for users' benefit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155531/question-is-very-popular-but-closed-not-constructive-shouldnt-it-be-reopene) See also: [Why are popular question like these closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184353/why-are-popular-question-like-these-closed) and [Half the 10 highest voted questions on SO are closed. Does this bother the SO team?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11259)

Answer (score 13):

Upvotes, as much as we wish they did, do not always mean a question is of high-quality and suitable for the site. More often than not, it simply indicates popularity. And popularity is not a good indicator if something should be open or not.

And it's not as if we are without means to reopen a question. If a question is closed, it can be reopened by those who have the privilege to vote accordingly. Or you could come to Meta, clearly present your case, and see if the community (or perhaps even a mod) is willing to reopen it.

Comment: "you could come to Meta, clearly present your case, and see if the community (or perhaps even a mod) is willing to reopen it." which i did.

Comment: No, you made a feature request with a sample case. If all you want is to see that particular question reopened, make that clear. But it's unlikely to happen, for reasons already stated.

Comment: i made that clear (even used the word 'clearly'). Last Sentence of my Post.

Comment: @Nils Then don't tag it [feature-request] and give it an appropriate title. As it stands, it's a feature request. And that's what I'm addressing.